# Query data sort lines by sumnums then display keywords in lines

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregate

I have this collection doc below:

```
{
    "data1": [{
        "info1": "keyword1",
        "info2": 211,
        "info3": "keyword3",
        "info4": "keyword4",
        "info5": "keyword5",
        "info6": "keyword6"
    }],
    "data2": "data2",
    "data3": "data3"
}
```

I want to sort data1.info2(int numbers) from big to small and return 
 data1.info1(keyword1)
 just show one line，I tried:

```
db.collection1.find(
  {"data1.info2":{$gt:150}},
  {"data1.$":1}
).forEach(function(doc){db.new.insert(doc)})
```

to create a new collection,then use
 db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{"data1.info2":{$gt:200}},{$group:{"_id":{"newinfo":"$data1.info2"}}}])
to aggregate the data,then show the result as I want to,then get a little problem by sorting the result by number,to be continue...

Comment: What are you expecting? To sort the keys? To sort documents based on one of the keys? It would be clearer if you posted what a result looked like that you wanted, since you have syntax so wrong here. By the look of it, you have more than just one problem. Also please learn from the edits I just made as to how to format a post here.

Comment: You can actually edit your question yourself if all the other newbs stop trying to edit it to gain some rep that is. Please try typing in the expected look of the result you want into your question. Not in comments. And you are typing in "aggregation" or "update" operators into a `.find()`. That will not work, which is why it does not help to keep typing them in. Just show the document output you expect. Then we can explain everything you are doing wrong.